# Как изучить asp.net и ms sql server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Я хочу изучить asp.net и ms sql server. Для себя напишу интернет магазин. Я хочу сразу начать с практики параллельно читая книги по этим вопросам. Но подскажите, какой алгоритм моих действий должен быть?

Comment: [выбери себе книгу из этого списка, почитай отзывы на том же озоне и купи](http://www.cyberforum.ru/asp-net/thread189468.html)

Comment: книги я выбрал. Меня интересуют не книги. Одного чтения мало. Меня интересует как совмещать теорию с практикой. Это ведь не упражнения после каждой главы.

Comment: Если идешь по книге - упражнения в конце главы, если сам задание придумываешь - ответ в книге на разных страницах. Логика проще некуда.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/309017)

Comment: @AK Это вроде вопрос. Как сюда комментарий из очереди проверок попал?

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый ArniLand,

Никак, никоим другим образом, как читать книги (следовать онлайн-курсу), читая по ходу обо всех сопутствующих терминах, не получится (как пример, невозможно понять ASP, не зная, как работает вебсервер и пр.). Тысячи молодых людей заходят сюда и задают такие вопросы. Все мы проходили через это. Лучше сразу, с самого начала, поверить, что без труда рыбки не будет. День за днем (сначала будет непонятно многое), будет казаться, что стоишь на месте - самое главное не разочаровываться и продолжать - это ЕДИНСТВЕННАЯ формула успеха. Спустя уже месяц ты поймешь, что знаешь уже настолько больше, чем знал в самом начале. А дальше - легче, поверь, опыт будет приходить быстрее, чем думаешь. Самое главное начать и не забрасывать. Всего месяц.